# Is a sub-document in MongoDB the same as a sub-object?

Tags: mongodb

In MongoDB an item within a collection is called a *document*. To put it simply, a *document* is to a *collection*  what a *record* is to a *table* in a relational database. Now I've more than times already read the term *sub-document*.

What exactly is this?

Is it just a sub-object of the document? E.g., if I have the document:

```
{
  foo: 'xyz',
  bar: {
    baz: 'bla'
  }
}
```

Is `bar` then the *sub-document* of the outer document, or is there more to a sub-document? What are its characteristics?

I could not find an explanation of the term in MongoDB's documentation, but maybe it's in there and I have just not found it.

Can anybody explain this to me (or provide a hint where I can look it up)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just different terminology. Yes, sub-objects are the same as sub-documents.

For example, when you're working with an object-document mapper (ODM), it might use terms: "document" and "embedded documents" (or "subdocuments"). Because you work with such library in some programming language (ruby, for example), one needs to differentiate mongodb documents from regular ruby objects. Otherwise conversations about the program would be ambiguous.

On the other hand, when you're directly querying the database from javascript shell, it's all just objects to you (which can contain other objects).

This is how I understand it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `bar` is a sub document. In the mongodb docs, they call fields with the json type Object documents. If it's embedded in another document, like bar in your example, that is what they call a sub document.